# Powershell command to update azure cloud service (extended support) with files in blob

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cloud-services

In the Azure portal, my Cloud Service (Extended Support) gets updated pretty frequently and swapped with another Cloud Service (Extended Support) instance.  I have a script that uploads the CSPKG, CSDEF, and CSCFG files to blob storage.  This works fine.

I then go to the portal, find the instance I want to update, click **Update**, change to Blob storage, browse to the files I uploaded and click on the update button.  This kicks off the process and about 7-9 minutes later the instance is ready to use.

I am trying to replicate this update process in PowerShell, and though it appears that it works, the instance never actually updates.  It finds the cloud service just fine.
This is what I have put together:

```
    # Get an SAS token to CSPKG
    Write-Host ("$(Get-Date -f $timeStampFormat) Getting CSPKG Shared Access Signature (SAS) token") -ForegroundColor DarkCyan 
    #$tokenStartTime = Get-Date
    #$tokenEndTime = $tokenStartTime.AddYears(1)
    #$cspkgToken = New-AzStorageBlobSASToken -Container “vs-deploy” -Blob “MyCloudService.cspkg” -Permission rwd -StartTime $tokenStartTime -ExpiryTime $tokenEndTime -Context $storageAccount.Context 

$cloudService = (Get-AzCloudService) |
    Where-Object {
        $_.networkProfile.LoadBalancerConfiguration.FrontendIPConfiguration.PublicIPAddressId -like "*MyIP"
    }    
$stagingServiceName = $cloudService.Name

    Write-Host ("$(Get-Date -f $timeStampFormat) Deploying to {0} Cloud Service" -f $stagingServiceName) -ForegroundColor DarkCyan

# Load the CSCFG XML into a string from local drive
$cscfgContent = Get-Content $cscfgFilePath | Out-String

 try {
        Write-Host "URI for blob: "$cspkgBlob.ICloudBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri
        # Update the cloud service
        $cloudService.PackageUrl = $cspkgBlob.ICloudBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri
        $cloudService.Configuration = $cscfgContent
        $cloudService | Update-AzCloudService
    } catch {
        Write-Host ("$(Get-Date -f $timeStampFormat) Cloud Service {0} failed to update: {1}" -f $service, $_.Exception.Message) -ForegroundColor Red
        break;
    }

Write-Host ("$(Get-Date -f $timeStampFormat) Finished")
```

First question is: Why is there no mention of the CSDEF file when the portal requires it to update?

Second question: One of the methods I tried required the SAS token but this one doesn't seem to.  Did I miss something?

Third question: I could not find a way to read the CSCFG file from the blob to resorted to reading it from my local drive.  What is the proper way to get it from the blob?

Final question:  Even though this appears to update, the instance doesn't change.  What am I missing?

Thanks,
JayTee

Comment: refer this [MSDOC](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/cloud-services-extended-support/deploy-powershell.md)

Comment: I've read that.  The problem with that article is that is shows how to create a NEW cloud service deployment, not update an existing one.  It is not feasible or desirable to delete the cloud service and recreate it each time. Nor should it be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you'll get the most value from the [Cloud Services - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/cloud-services/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP) docs. Create and Update are the same operation in the world of Cloud Services (Extended Support).

1. I'm not sure why Portal wants the CSDEF. I don't see a requirement for it in the raw REST API.
2. You can provide either the raw CSCFG or a SAS URI to your CSCFG per the REST docs. You can supply the raw CSCFG via `configuration` (as you're doing above) or you can supply a SAS URI via `configurationUrl`. (It does look like the docs have a typo there- The second sentence of `configurationUrl` should read "The service <strike>package</strike> configuration URL can be....")
3. See #2. You can use the SAS URI for your CSCFG blob by using the `configurationUrl` instead of `configuration` in the `CloudServiceProperties`.
4. I don't think we have enough information here. Consider double-checking that you're providing the expected new package and configuration and not accidentally providing the old one?